# Replace elements in one array from elements in other array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, functional-programming

I am having two arrays. Size of first array is larger than second one.

```
 var first  = (1 to 20).toArray
 var second = (1 to 5).toArray
```

I want to Replace first **n** elements of **first** array with the elements of **second** array. Where **n** is length of second array.
Using **For** loop I can easily do this in following way

```
 var n = second.length
 for(i <- 0 until n)
 {
  first(i) = second(i)
 }
```

I want to ask is there any other way to perform same operation in Scala in more functional way?

Comment: What do you mean by "more functional way"? Are you looking for a solution without mutating the first array?

Comment: @k0pernikus yes. I am looking for alternative of For loop.

Comment: You could use [`copyToArray`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Array.html#copyToArray(xs:Array[A]):Unit) like, `second.copyToArray(first)`.  Also, for what you need you could replace `var` with `val`.

Comment: In the end, even a functional approach will loop the data. Furthermore, a functional approach will create another array consisting of the result and therefore have a larger memory consumption.

Comment: If you want to write in a functional way, you should begin by avoiding ever using `Array` in the first place, just sayin'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var first  = (1 to 20).toArray
var second = (1 to 5).toArray

val third = second ++ first.drop(second.length)
```

result:

```
third: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Comment: This IIRC either returns a vector or IndexedSeq[Int], so `toArray` may be necessary.

Comment: first = second ++ first.drop(second.length)
This will return first array with updated elements

Comment: @yari yes, but since you asked a more functional way, it is better to use val´s instead of vars, if you really want to replace and keep vars, then it is exactly how you wrote.